# Quantitatively determining a "baseline" value for a dataset

Tags: time-series, quantiles, baseline

I'm wondering if there's a clean way to quantitatively find the "baseline" of a data set, or more specifically, a threshold below which the majority of samples are clustered. For the example below, I have horizontal lines plotted for the outliers (upper inner fence), 99th percentile, and 99.9th percentile (red, purple, and green, respectively). It would seem that either outliers or the 99th percentile appear to be the best of these options for this data set but I am wondering if there's a way to perform this more quantitatively and methodically rather than visually.

[image: Time-series w/ outliers and percentiles]

Comment: This strongly relates to your research/business question. You are correct to realise that any algorithm should be compared against some relevant baseline (e.g. "*label $x_i$ as an outlier if it is 4 or more standard deviations $\sigma_x$ away from the mean $\mu_x$*") that is specific to the application. For all we know, for example, this data has *no* outliers at all and the 99th+ percentile values are naturally occurring as in every other dataset (cause ultimately "some" 1% of our observations have to be larger than that 99th quantile value).

Comment: @usεr11852 Thank you for the comment. I'm aware there is no cookie-cutter solution for this but my intention with this question is to source ideas for a better way to quantify the threshold of "bottom clustering" seen in this example, rather than guessing percentiles and arbitrarily choosing a visual match. Can I use some kind of statistical test to identify the clustered samples? If not, can you suggest a more methodical approach?